# Test of rational number as a terminating decimal number using $2^m \cdot 5^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, fractions, rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

I do not understand why $q$ needs to be equal to $2^m \times 5^n$ for $\frac{p}{q}$to be a terminating rational number.

Why cannot $q$ be equal to $2^m\times 3^n$?

Is there any documentation that I can read up on this?

Comment: The result is: *assuming* $p/q$ is a fraction in *lowest terms*, then it's decimal form is terminating if and only if there are $m,n \ge 0$ such that $q=2^m5^n.$ [your question doesn't make $m,n$ exponents as they should be, and doesn't mention that the criterion assumes $\gcd(p,q)=1.$]

Comment: Because we've chosen the product of 2 and 5 as our number base.  If we counted in base 6 or 12, powers of three *would* be terminating "decimals".

Comment: To build intuition, take a look at an example of a terminating rational number such as $0.123$.  Recognize that this example is equal to $\frac{123}{1000}$.  For another example $0.12345678$ is equal to $\frac{12345678}{100000000}$.  I should hope you can see a pattern with regards to how we can use powers of $10$ to our advantage here.  From there, it is a matter of properties of primes and introductory number theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One definition we can use for a "terminating decimal" is that a number $x$ has a terminating decimal expansion if for some integer $n$, $x\cdot 10^n$ is an integer. In other words, if we can shift the decimal point a finite number of times to the right and end up nothing else after the decimal, that decimal expansion terminates.

For rational numbers ($x=\frac{p}{q}$, $p$ and $q$ are coprime), this means that we need $\frac{p\cdot10^n}{q}$ to be an integer. But since $p$ and $q$ are by definition coprime, this means that $q$ has to divide $10^n$ evenly. Looking at prime factorizations, $10^n=2^n5^n$, and $q$ must have a subset of these prime factors. Thus for the number to have a terminating decimal expansion, $q$ must be expressible as $2^{m_1}5^{m_2}$ for some $m_1,m_2<n$. But since $n$ can be arbitrarily large, this result holds for any integers $m_1,m_2$.

---

Notice that the allowable factors $2$ and $5$ for $q$ depend only on the prime factorization of $10$, the base in our decimal system. This has the consequence that in a different base system, you may have a different set of allowable factors for $q$. For example, in Base-12 ($12=2^23$), a rational number's "decimal" expansion terminates if $q=2^{m_1}3^{m_2}$. Likewise, in hexadecimal ($16=2^4$), a rational number terminates only if $q=2^m$.